# Advanced Conditional Random Number Generator in MS-EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, macos, random, excel-formula

In Excel, I have a table with items, each with a negative or positive value. I am wondering if there is a simple approach to selecting a random subset of **integer** numbers from the table whose sum could be 0 or close to it (lets say after k iterations).

Several of the solutions mentioned on stackexchange alluded to the (NUMBER/SUM_OF_NUMBER_COLUMN)*TARGET_SUM approach, but it does not work for all cases, [ex: if the sum is 0]

Eg:

In the image attached, you input the # of items to be selected and the target sum. The solution is expected to return a combination of the indicated # of items from the table [BEST SELECTION] such the the target sum is met or is close to it (+/-1 deviation is ideal).

**As you can see only column 1 is guaranteed to be unique, i.e. there may be duplicate instances of item names (as seen in column 2), and/or different item names with the same value (as seen in column 3).**

[image: Example Table]

I was able to implement something with a combination of INDEX(), RANDBETWEEN() and VLOOKUP(), to generate numbers but I could not check the sum requirement and for some reason VLOOKUP() only returned valid results for items with a positive value.

The formula I tried with is:

```
VLOOKUP(INDEX(Table3[[#Data],['#]],RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(Tabl‌​e3[[#Data],['#]])),1‌​),Table3,2,FALSE)
```

But I am not able to check for the sum and ensure VLOOKUP can deal with duplicates and negative values.

Comment: Include the formula that does not work

Comment: @RobinMackenzie 

I use the following formula to lookup a random item


**VLOOKUP(INDEX(Table3[[#Data],['#]],RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(Table3[[#Data],['#]])),1),Table3,2,FALSE)**

But I am not able to check for the sum and ensure VLOOKUP can deal with duplicates and negative values.

Comment: I used this formula in `TEST1` that shows `A` on the picture you attached: `=IF(ROW()-ROW(F$4)>=F$2,"",INDEX($B$2:$B$11,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($B$2:$B$11)),1))`. And the next cell is `=IF(F4="","",INDEX($B$2:$C$11,MATCH(F4,$B$2:$B$11,0),2))`. It will pick negative numbers and determine how many cells should display results. But to achieve your goal, you will definitely create a VBA for that. What I tried before is run that macro until the requirements are met but sometimes it will take very long time to complete the task. Hope someone here can give you a better suggestions and good luck.